# Windows 10 can"t be installed beyond 33% from DVD iso

Tags: dvd, iso-image, windows-10-upgrade

I am trying for free upgrade of Windows 7 64 bit Home Premium to W#indows 10. I have managed to download windows 10 and save it in DVD iso. But I am unable to install windows 10.  The installation process continues till 33% installation complete.  Beyond that suddenly installation stops and reverts back to windows 7 with message "Something happened Windows 10 installation failed Ok."  Now the only option for me is to restart/reboot PC and start the process all over again which takes around 35/40 minutes and once it reaches 33% installation completes , the system reverts back to Windows 7 and down comes the caption "windows 10 installation failed".  I have restarted and tried to install windows 10 several times but not succeed.  Can anyone help me to find out the reasons as I have also failed to install even after disabling Anti virus programme "Net Protector".

Comment: See "Installation fails or becomes non-responsive at certain point during setup 18%, 62%, Driver Migration, Applying Settings." [on the chart on this page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-troubleshoot-common-setup-and-stop-errors/324d5a5f-d658-456c-bb82-b1201f735683)

Comment: You may want to check the Event Logs to see what's going on.  Just go to the control panel and type 'View Event Log'.  Check through those logs to see if it can give you a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem now. Followed all the fixes I could find which didn't help.

I eventually (which probably should've been the first thing to do) checked the event logs and found the error code **80070714** for the Windows 10 upgrade, which in turn lead me to [this page](https://espressocode.wordpress.com/2015/08/05/upgrade-to-windows-10-error-80070714/).

**The solution was to disable all SQL Server services running on the system. Tried running the upgrade again, and was successful.**